# React-toastify duplicating toast

Tags: reactjs, toast, react-toastify

I have a mods page in my app which only moderators and administrators should be able to access. If a person tries to access it by directly typing the URL I have some logic that would redirect them.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import createNotification from "../../../addNotification";
import getRole from "../../../authentication";

const ModHome = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const role = getRole();

    if (!["administrator", "moderator"].includes(role)) {
        createNotification("You are not a moderator", "error");
        history.push("/admin-login");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Mod page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ModHome
```

The logic works fine. I get redirected to the login page but for some reason this happens
[image]

I already checked and the toasts have different IDs and the function gets called only once so why am I getting 2 notifications?

Update: Here's the createNofication code:

```
import {toast} from "react-toastify";

export default function createNotification(message, type) {
    const options = {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 5000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
    };
    switch(type) {
      case "success":
        toast.success(message, options);
        break;
      case "warning":
        toast.warn(message, options);
        break;
      case "error":
        toast.error(message, options);
        break;
      case "info":
        toast.info(message, options);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `createNotification` code?

Comment: I would also suggest that you wrap this `if` code with a `useEffect` so you can have a better control of when you want it to run.

Comment: @MazenAk Edited the question with the code

Comment: @DanielBaldi Somehow your comment fixed it. If you want you can answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe that the function is being called only once? Running this `if` code in the body of your component will cause its execution everytime that the component renders or rerenders, so I believe that this function is being called multiple times.

If you wrap it with a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array you will probably stop seeing the duplicate.